# Incorrect password encryption

Tags: symfony, encryption

I have a small password encryption problem ^^
in my database the passwords are present, and have to present, in this form:

> VwBybV5ATQ9RkdvvVZNOlldEEDU9tDjttju7t8l+HeVe4nskHeMpbuCoQsqqORUQKZ1pg7gGtFocpkSIw8N9kA==

and right now I have a function that needs to generate a password for me. Unfortunately the encryption is not good, because that's what I get:

> YmY1NzFkM2VkODYwOGQ1OWFlMTRiZDVkOTc3ZDFkNzQ0ODIzN2U5NWMzNzU0ZjI1Y2U4MTZhYzBiYmExYWJjZTg2Y2JjNzYyM2QwYTJmMDUwYWJiMzQxMjliYjBjYWQxMGZiMzliYzk3OGQwZjYxMGU3Y2E0NjE0ZTkxYzFiYmM=

my code :

```
public function lostpasswordAction(Request $request)
{
    $success = '';
    $string = '';
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $max = strlen($characters) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $max)];
    }

    if ($request->request->get('email') !== null) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User')->findByEmail($request->request->get('email'));

        if (is_null($user)) {
            $response = new JsonResponse('Not Found');
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
            return $response;
        }

        $login = $user[0]->getEmail();
        $password = $string;

        $user[0]->setPassword(hash('sha512',$password));
        $em->persist($user[0]);
        $em->flush();

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Subject')
            ->setFrom('no-reply@noreply.com')
            ->setTo($request->request->get('email'))
            ->setBody(
                $this->renderView(
                    'emails/lostpassword.txt.twig',
                    array(
                        'login' => $login,
                        'password' => $password
                    )
                ),
                'text/plain'
            );
        $return = $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

        $success = 'Email sent';

        return new JsonResponse($success);
    }

    $response = new JsonResponse('POST only');
    $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    return $response;
}
```

Can someone help me so I get the right shape please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You shouldn't "encrypt" passwords, you should be hashing them.

Comment: @ConorThompson it's common that people mix the meanings of those words, but you can see in the code that it's being hashed

Comment: Are you totally sure that both passwords you inputted are exactly the same? And are you sure they're being hashed the same way, with the same algorithm?

Comment: If you are allowing `Symfony` to authenticate a user while logging in, You should probably use `Symfony` built-in Password encrypt as defined in security.yml for each `user_provider`. Which version of Symfony are you using?